# Code to perform validations on time series data

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns

Scenario:

I have a time series data published to a Queue (Kafka). Each message (kafka message) when consumed from the topic needs to be validated by rules which are created in a datastore. These rules are called as filters in our case.

A filter object looks like below.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "id", "name", "field", "condition", "action" })
public class Filter implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7488270474843121039L;
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("field")
    private String field;
    @JsonProperty("condition")
    private CONDITION condition;
    @JsonProperty("action")
    private ACTION action;
    @JsonProperty("type")
    private TYPE type;

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("field")
    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }

    @JsonProperty("field")
    public void setField(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    @JsonProperty("condition")
    public CONDITION getCondition() {
        return condition;
    }

    @JsonProperty("condition")
    public void setCondition(CONDITION condition) {
        this.condition = condition;
    }

    @JsonProperty("action")
    public ACTION getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    @JsonProperty("action")
    public void setAction(ACTION action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    @JsonProperty("type")
    public TYPE getType() {
        return type;
    }

    @JsonProperty("type")
    public void setType(TYPE type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

The service which consumes and performs validation is as below.

```
@Service
public class ConsumerService {

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConsumerService.class);

    // TODO - consider renaming the interface?
    @Autowired
    private IFilterService filterService;

    @Autowired
    private ProducerService producerService;

    public void consume() {

        String topic = "daas.filter.json.incoming";
        String consGroup = "syslogJsonconsumer";

        KafkaConsumer<String, JsonNode> consumer = new GenericConsumer<String, JsonNode>().initialize(topic, consGroup,
                STREAMSERDE.STRINGDESER, STREAMSERDE.JSONDESER);

        logger.debug("filter Kafka Consumer Initialized......");

        try {
            while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, JsonNode> records = consumer.poll(100);

                for (ConsumerRecord<String, JsonNode> record : records) {

                    logger.debug("record.offset() = " + record.offset() + " : record.key() = " + record.key());

                    // TODO - receive avro message instead of JSONNode.
                    JsonNode jsonNode = record.value();

                    logger.info("##Filter Consumer##>>incoming Message = " + jsonNode);

                    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    NormalizedSyslogMessage syslog = (NormalizedSyslogMessage) objectMapper.convertValue(jsonNode,
                            NormalizedSyslogMessage.class);

                    // TODO - consider moving below code out of Consumer.

                    // apply filters on the incoming message. Returns isDropped.
                    boolean isDropped = applyFilter(syslog);
                    logger.info("message [" + syslog.getKey() + " - isDropped##>> = " + isDropped);

                    if (!isDropped) {
                        // TODO forward the rawSyslogMessage to Correlation
                        // Service
                        producerService.produce(syslog);
                    }

                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error occured while processing message", e);
        } finally {
            logger.debug("debupe kafka consume is closing");
            consumer.close();
        }

    }

    // load filters for a given party and apply on the rawSyslogMessage.
    private boolean applyFilter(NormalizedSyslogMessage message) throws EntityNotFoundException {

        boolean isDropped = false;

        logger.info("---applyFilter()::rawSyslog :" + message);

        String partyID = message.getPartyID();

        // load all filters for the given party
        List<Filter> filters = filterService.getAll(partyID);

        if (filters != null) {
            for (Filter filter : filters) {
                if (filter.getType() == TYPE.NUMBER_COMPARATOR) {
                    if (filter.getCondition() == CONDITION.GREATER && filter.getAction() == ACTION.ALLOW) {
                        if (message.getSeverity() > Long.parseLong(filter.getField())) {
                            logger.info("message forwarded for correlation");
                        } else {
                            logger.info("message is dropped");
                        }
                    } else if (filter.getCondition() == CONDITION.LESSER && filter.getAction() == ACTION.ALLOW) {
                        if (message.getSeverity() < Long.parseLong(filter.getField())) {
                            logger.info("message forwarded for correlation");
                        } else {
                            logger.info("message is dropped");
                        }
                    } else if (filter.getCondition() == CONDITION.GREATER && filter.getAction() == ACTION.DISCARD) {
                        if (message.getSeverity() > Long.parseLong(filter.getField())) {
                            logger.info("message is dropped");
                        } else {
                            logger.info("message forwarded for correlation");
                        }
                    } else if (filter.getCondition() == CONDITION.LESSER && filter.getAction() == ACTION.DISCARD) {
                        if (message.getSeverity() < Long.parseLong(filter.getField())) {
                            logger.info("message is dropped");
                        } else {
                            logger.info("message forwarded for correlation");
                        }
                    } else if (filter.getCondition() == CONDITION.EQUALS && filter.getAction() == ACTION.ALLOW) {
                        if (message.getSeverity() == Long.parseLong(filter.getField())) {
                            logger.info("message forwarded for correlation");
                        } else {
                            logger.info("message is dropped");
                        }
                    } else if (filter.getCondition() == CONDITION.EQUALS && filter.getAction() == ACTION.DISCARD) {
                        if (message.getSeverity() == Long.parseLong(filter.getField())) {
                            logger.info("message is dropped");
                        } else {
                            logger.info("message forwarded for correlation");
                        }
                    } else if (filter.getCondition() == CONDITION.BETWEEN && filter.getAction() == ACTION.ALLOW) {
                        String[] operands = filter.getField().split(",");
                        if (Long.parseLong(operands[0]) <= message.getSeverity()
                                && Long.parseLong(operands[1]) >= message.getSeverity()) {
                            logger.info("message forwarded for correlation");
                        } else {
                            logger.info("message is dropped");
                        }
                    } else if (filter.getCondition() == CONDITION.BETWEEN && filter.getAction() == ACTION.DISCARD) {
                        String[] operands = filter.getField().split(",");
                        if (Long.parseLong(operands[0]) <= message.getSeverity()
                                && Long.parseLong(operands[1]) >= message.getSeverity()) {
                            logger.info("message is dropped");
                        } else {
                            logger.info("message forwarded for correlation");
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The CONDITION or ACTION is not supported");
                    }
                } else if (filter.getType() == TYPE.STRING_COMPARATOR) {
                    if (filter.getCondition() == CONDITION.MATCHES && filter.getAction() == ACTION.ALLOW) {
                        if (message.getMessage().contains(filter.getField())) {
                            logger.info("message forwarded for correlation");
                        } else {
                            logger.info("message is dropped");
                        }
                    } else if (filter.getCondition() == CONDITION.MATCHES && filter.getAction() == ACTION.DISCARD) {
                        if (message.getMessage().contains(filter.getField())) {
                            logger.info("message is dropped");
                        } else {
                            logger.info("message forwarded for correlation");
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The filter type " + filter.getType() + " is not supported. ");
                }
            }
        }
        return isDropped;
    }
}
```

The ConsumerService consumes the messages and using the unique id in the message it gets all the filters.

After getting all the filters the message is validated on the filter list and checks if the message needs to be forwarded for further processing.

I would like my code to be reviewed on mainly the design and what are the best practices i could follow to avoid clumsiness.

**Edit: Adding the new changes to the code**

After giving a lot of thought i have create interface for generating and evaluating expressions. Created a Builder class to create Operands class which caters to 2 to 3 operands for an expression generation

```
@Service
public class ConsumerService {

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConsumerService.class);

    // TODO - consider renaming the interface?
    @Autowired
    private IFilterService filterService;

    @Autowired
    private ProducerService producerService;

    public void consume() {

        String topic = "daas.filter.json.incoming";
        String consGroup = "syslogJsonconsumer";

        KafkaConsumer<String, JsonNode> consumer = new GenericConsumer<String, JsonNode>().initialize(topic, consGroup,
                STREAMSERDE.STRINGDESER, STREAMSERDE.JSONDESER);

        logger.debug("filter Kafka Consumer Initialized......");

        try {
            while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, JsonNode> records = consumer.poll(100);

                for (ConsumerRecord<String, JsonNode> record : records) {

                    logger.debug("record.offset() = " + record.offset() + " : record.key() = " + record.key());

                    // TODO - receive avro message instead of JSONNode.
                    JsonNode jsonNode = record.value();

                    logger.info("##Filter Consumer##>>incoming Message = " + jsonNode);

                    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    NormalizedSyslogMessage syslog = (NormalizedSyslogMessage) objectMapper.convertValue(jsonNode,
                            NormalizedSyslogMessage.class);

                    // TODO - consider moving below code out of Consumer.

                    // apply filters on the incoming message. Returns isDropped.
                    boolean isDropped = applyFilter(syslog);
                    logger.info("message [" + syslog.getKey() + " - isDropped##>> = " + isDropped);

                    if (!isDropped) {
                        // TODO forward the rawSyslogMessage to Correlation
                        // Service
                        producerService.produce(syslog);
                    }

                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error occured while processing message", e);
        } finally {
            logger.debug("debupe kafka consume is closing");
            consumer.close();
        }

    }

    // load filters for a given party and apply on the rawSyslogMessage.
    private boolean applyFilter(NormalizedSyslogMessage message) throws Exception {

        boolean isDropped = false;

        logger.info("---applyFilter()::rawSyslog :" + message);

        String partyID = message.getPartyID();

        // load all filters for the given party
        List<Filter> filters = filterService.getAll(partyID);

        if (filters != null) {
            for (Filter filter : filters) {
                Operands operands;
                if (filter.getType() == TYPE.NUMBER_COMPARATOR) {
                    operands = new Operands.OperandsBuilder(Long.toString(message.getSeverity()), filter.getField())
                            .build();
                    if (filter.getCondition().equals(CONDITION.BETWEEN)) {
                        String[] fields = filter.getField().split(",");
                        operands = new Operands.OperandsBuilder(fields[0], Long.toString(message.getSeverity()))
                                .middleOperand(fields[1]).build();
                    }
                    Expression expression = ExpressionPicker.pickExpressionBy(filter.getCondition(), filter.getAction(),
                            operands);
                    isDropped = expression.evaluate();
                } else if (filter.getType() == TYPE.STRING_COMPARATOR) {
                    operands = new Operands.OperandsBuilder(message.getMessage(), filter.getField())
                            .build();
                    Expression expression = ExpressionPicker.pickExpressionBy(filter.getCondition(), filter.getAction(),
                            operands);
                    isDropped = expression.evaluate();
                } else {
                    throw new Exception("Filter invalid, please check.");
                }
            }
        }
        return isDropped;
    }
}

/*
   Interface for implementing different kinds of expressions
*/

public interface Expression {
    boolean evaluate();
}

/*
    Factory to generate different expressions.
*/

public class ExpressionPicker {

    public static Expression pickExpressionBy(CONDITION condition, ACTION action, Operands operands) {
        if (condition.name().equals("GREATER") && action.name().equals("ALLOW")
                || condition.name().equals("LESSER") && action.name().equals("DISCARD")) {
            return new IsGreaterExpression(Integer.parseInt(operands.get_leftOperand()),
                    Integer.parseInt(operands.get_rightOperand()));
        } else if (condition.name().equals("GREATER") && action.name().equals("DISCARD")
                || condition.name().equals("LESSER") && action.name().equals("ALLOW")) {
            return new IsLesserExpression(Integer.parseInt(operands.get_leftOperand()),
                    Integer.parseInt(operands.get_rightOperand()));
        } else if (condition.name().equals("EQUALS") && action.name().equals("ALLOW")) {
            return new IsEqualsExpression(Integer.parseInt(operands.get_leftOperand()),
                    Integer.parseInt(operands.get_rightOperand()), ACTION.ALLOW);
        } else if (condition.name().equals("EQUALS") && action.name().equals("DISCARD")) {
            return new IsEqualsExpression(Integer.parseInt(operands.get_leftOperand()),
                    Integer.parseInt(operands.get_rightOperand()), ACTION.DISCARD);
        } else if (condition.name().equals("BETWEEN") && action.name().equals("ALLOW")) {
            return new IsInBetweenExpression(Integer.parseInt(operands.get_leftOperand()),
                    Integer.parseInt(operands.get_rightOperand()), Integer.parseInt(operands.get_middleOperand()),
                    ACTION.ALLOW);
        } else if (condition.name().equals("BETWEEN") && action.name().equals("DISCARD")) {
            return new IsInBetweenExpression(Integer.parseInt(operands.get_leftOperand()),
                    Integer.parseInt(operands.get_rightOperand()), Integer.parseInt(operands.get_middleOperand()),
                    ACTION.DISCARD);
        } else if (condition.name().equals("MATCHES") && action.name().equals("ALLOW")) {
            return new IsMatchingWithExpression(operands.get_leftOperand(), operands.get_rightOperand(), ACTION.ALLOW);
        } else if (condition.name().equals("MATCHES") && action.name().equals("DISCARD")) {
            return new IsMatchingWithExpression(operands.get_leftOperand(), operands.get_rightOperand(),
                    ACTION.DISCARD);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input");
        }
    }

}


public class IsEqualsExpression implements Expression {

    private int _leftOperand;
    private int _rightOperand;
    private ACTION _action;

    public IsEqualsExpression(int leftOperand, int rightOperand, ACTION action) {
        this._leftOperand = leftOperand;
        this._rightOperand = rightOperand;
        this._action = action;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean evaluate() {
        if (_action.name() == "ALLOW" && _leftOperand == _rightOperand) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}


public class IsGreaterExpression implements Expression {

    private int _leftOperand;
    private int _rightOperand;

    public IsGreaterExpression(int leftOperand, int rightOperand) {
        this._leftOperand = leftOperand;
        this._rightOperand = rightOperand;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean evaluate() {
        if (_leftOperand > _rightOperand) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}



public class IsInBetweenExpression implements Expression {

    private int _leftOperand;
    private int _rightOperand;
    private int _middleOperand;
    private ACTION _action;

    public IsInBetweenExpression(int leftOperand, int rightOperand, int middleOperand, ACTION action) {
        this._leftOperand = leftOperand;
        this._rightOperand = rightOperand;
        this._middleOperand = middleOperand;
        this._action = action;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean evaluate() {
        if (_action.name() == "ALLOW") {
            return getRange();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean getRange() {
        if (_leftOperand <= _middleOperand && _rightOperand >= _middleOperand) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}


public class IsLesserExpression implements Expression {

    private int _leftOperand;
    private int _rightOperand;

    public IsLesserExpression(int leftOperand, int rightOperand) {
        this._leftOperand = leftOperand;
        this._rightOperand = rightOperand;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean evaluate() {
        if (_leftOperand > _rightOperand) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}

public class IsMatchingWithExpression implements Expression {

    private String _rightOperand;
    private String _leftOperand;
    private ACTION _action;

    public IsMatchingWithExpression(String inputString, String patternString, ACTION action) {
        this._rightOperand = inputString;
        this._leftOperand = patternString;
        this._action = action;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean evaluate() {
        if (_action.name() == "ALLOW") {
            return getMatchResult();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean getMatchResult() {
        if (_rightOperand.contains(_leftOperand)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}

/* Builder class to build operands to feed to the expressions for end result.

public class Operands {
    private final String _rightOperand;
    private final String _leftOperand;
    private final String _middleOperand;

    private Operands(OperandsBuilder builder) {
        this._rightOperand = builder._rightOperand;
        this._leftOperand = builder._leftOperand;
        this._middleOperand = builder._middleOperand;
    }

    public String get_rightOperand() {
        return _rightOperand;
    }

    public String get_leftOperand() {
        return _leftOperand;
    }

    public String get_middleOperand() {
        return _middleOperand;
    }

    public static class OperandsBuilder {
        private final String _rightOperand;
        private final String _leftOperand;
        private String _middleOperand;

        public OperandsBuilder(String leftOperand, String rightOperand) {
            this._rightOperand = rightOperand;
            this._leftOperand = leftOperand;
        }

        public OperandsBuilder middleOperand(String value) {
            this._middleOperand = value;
            return this;
        }

        public Operands build() {
            return new Operands(this);
        }
    }

}
```

Please provide the suggestions to make the code better.

At this moment i am aware that the validation logic needs to be cleaned up but i am not aware of how it can be done. If anybody can help me cleaning up the code i would be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

Here are my comments:

1) In the first version of the consumer, you compared the enum values correctly.  However, in the edited version you suddenly decided to use the `String` names for comparison.  This is simply wrong. First, you have the popular bug of using `==` instead of `equals` in several places.  Second, using enum values allows the compiler to check you didn't mistype "EQUALS" in one of the (many) places you typed it.

2) Your expression picking logic in `pickExpressionBy` is overly complex and confusing in my eyes.  You pick an expression based on condition and action. this results in the confusing situation of returning `IsGreaterExpression` when the condition is `LESSER`.  A better approach would be to ignore the action during expression picking.  this way, the connection between the filter's `CONDITION` and the type of `Expression` is simpler and straightforward. The consumer gets the result of the `Expression`s evaluation, then queries the action and simply reverse the answer accordingly.

now, while we are talking about expression picking: your current logic goes though great length to enforce the assumption that "lesser then" is the opposite of "greater then" - so why did you write both expressions? you can write just one of them (for example "lesser then") and then in "greater then"'s `evaluate` method call `evaluate` of "lesser then" and return opposite value.

3) regarding responsibilities: if `Filter` holds the condition (and action) why not let it pick the expression? moreover, if we do decide that a `CONDITION` is all that is needed,  why not let the enum itself pick the expression?

4) regarding the `Expression`s: the `evaluate()` can be simplified:

```
public class IsGreaterExpression implements Expression {

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean evaluate() {
        return _leftOperand > _rightOperand;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Enum names and comparison

`CONDITION` and `ACTION` should be renamed as `Condition` and `Action` respectively, as Java types are usually not in CAPS. Also, when you want to compare equality of an `enum`, you shouldn't have to compare on its `name()`, but rather on the value itself:

```
// condition.name().equals("GREATER") && action.name().equals("ALLOW")
condition == GREATER && action == ALLOW
```

`==` is safe for comparing `enum` values as they are guaranteed to match the [same instance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9) within the same class-loader.

#### Boolean logic

A lot of your code

```
if (condition) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Can simplified to just `return condition`.

Also, (and this leads to the next section), you need to be more careful about how you apply negation via your `Action.DISCARD`, e.g. when you `DISCARD` `LESSER` values, you are `ALLOW`-ing both `GREATER` and also `EQUAL` values.

#### `ExpressionPicker` and `Expression`

While your `ExpressionPicker` and `Expression` is a step in the right direction, you should attempt to model it as a [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) for an `Operand`.

Then, you should consider adding some helper methods on your `Operand` to nicely parse the values to the required types, e.g. `int` in most cases.

So, assuming you end up with an `Operand` similar to the following interface:

```
interface Operand {
    int left();

    int middle();

    int right();

    String getLeft();

    String getRight();
}
```

And you have a bunch of extra `Condition` values to better handle the negation logic:

```
enum Condition {
    GREATER, GREATER_EQUALS, EQUALS, LESSER_EQUALS, LESSER, BETWEEN, MATCHES
}
```

You can model an enumerated type of `Expression` values as such:

```
enum Expression implements Predicate<Operand> {
    GREATER(op -> op.left() > op.right(),
            Map.of(Action.ALLOW, Condition.GREATER,
                    Action.DISCARD, Condition.LESSER_EQUALS)),
    GREATER_EQUALS(op -> op.left() >= op.right(),
            Map.of(Action.ALLOW, Condition.GREATER_EQUALS,
                    Action.DISCARD, Condition.LESSER)),
    EQUALS(op -> op.left() == op.right(),
            Map.of(Action.ALLOW, Condition.EQUALS)),
    NOT_EQUALS(op -> op.left() != op.right(),
            Map.of(Action.DISCARD, Condition.EQUALS)),
    LESSER_EQUALS(op -> op.left() <= op.right(),
            Map.of(Action.ALLOW, Condition.LESSER_EQUALS,
                    Action.DISCARD, Condition.GREATER)),
    LESSER(op -> op.left() < op.right(),
            Map.of(Action.ALLOW, Condition.LESSER,
                    Action.DISCARD, Condition.GREATER_EQUALS)),
    BETWEEN(op -> op.left() <= op.middle() && op.middle() <= op.right(),
            Map.of(Action.ALLOW, Condition.BETWEEN)),
    NOT_BETWEEN(op -> op.right() < op.middle() || op.middle() < op.left(),
            Map.of(Action.DISCARD, Condition.BETWEEN)),
    MATCHES(op -> op.getLeft().contains(op.getRight()),
            Map.of(Action.ALLOW, Condition.MATCHES)),
    NOT_MATCHES(op -> !op.getLeft().contains(op.getRight()),
            Map.of(Action.DISCARD, Condition.MATCHES));

    private static final Set<Expression> ALL = EnumSet.allOf(Expression.class);

    private final Predicate<Operand> op;
    private final Map<Action, Condition> conditions;

    Expression(Predicate<Operand> op, Map<Action, Condition> conditions) {
        this.op = op;
        this.conditions = conditions;
    }

    private boolean matches(Condition condition, Action action) {
        return conditions.get(action) == condition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(Operand operand) {
        return op.test(operand);
    }

    static boolean evaluate(Condition condition,
                            Action action,
                            Operand operand) {
        return ALL.stream()
                .filter(v -> v.matches(condition, action))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new)
                .test(operand);
    }
}
```

Over here, we map our conditions using the `Action` as the key, so that it can read something like: 'with the key to `ALLOW`, given the condition `GREATER`'.